# Dot symbol in java ant

Tags: java, ant

I am new to Java Ant programming and I see this snippet of code

```
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="${executor.jar.file}"/>
</classpath>
```

I see that the project has an `executor` folder, but what's the meaning of `.jar.file`?

In general, does `.` in these positions have a special meaning?

Comment: That looks like a "magic" string that gets replaced by a compile operations that will fill in the *actual* path later.  (For some definition of "magic")

Comment: The period (`.`) has no special meaning whatsoever.  `executor.jar.file` is just a 17-character property name.  The periods only serve to make it more readable.

Comment: cf. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot (`.`) character has no special meaning in ant. text enclosed in curly braces and prepended by a `$` sign (`${like-this-for-example}`) is a property that can be set dynamically by another ant target.